# How do I implement the map() function using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I'm a beginner and I'm still trying to understand some concepts. I basically have to rewrite the behavior of the map() function using a for loop.

Being an exercise from a course, part of the code has already been provided me:

```
// the global Array
var s = [23, 65, 98, 5];

Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback){
  var newArray = [];
  // Add your code below this line



  // Add your code above this line
  return newArray;
};

var new_s = s.myMap(function(item){
  return item * 2;
});
console.log(new_s);
```

I thought this way: map is a function with a function as parameter, so the "callback" in the parentheses has to be a function and as its goal is to execute the function to every element of an array I'll need indeed a for loop and to pass an array as parameter.

so this is what I wrote:

```
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback){
    var newArray = [];
    // Add your code below this line
        for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
           newArray.push(this[i].callback);
        } 
    // Add your code above this line
    return newArray;
  }
```

I basically put a for cycle where "this" is supposed to be the array which uses the map() function but I'm not sure it's logically correct. Then I pushed into the array the result given by using the "callback" function to the actual element in the loop.

Unfortunately the result is an array of empty strings.

This is what the console shows me:

```
,,,
```

Thank you in advance, hope you can help to figure it out

Comment: You need to call the `callback` with your elements as an argument. Currently, you’re just reading a random property called `callback` off your elements.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill

Comment: `callback(this[i])` instead of `this[i].callback`

Comment: Firstly, I appreciate the effort you put into the question, and it must be the start of university or something because today is full of questions that have no effort in them. The other comments should assist you - but there's a polyfill ready-made for you I hope it'll give you some insight, and it's freely available on mdn. It's just a quick google search away! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill

Comment: This is a great, well-written question!  The answers and comments should help you.  But I agree with zfrisch; it's wonderful to see questions that show real effort and clearly explain the setting (coursework) and your thinking, as well as demonstrating real effort.

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the `callback` with the current value of `this[i]`.

```js
var s = [23, 65, 98, 5];
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback){
    var newArray = [];
    // Add your code below this line
        for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
           newArray.push(callback(this[i])); //pass the value of this[i] to the callback function.
        } 
    // Add your code above this line
    return newArray;
  }
var new_s = s.myMap(function(item){
  return item * 2;
});
console.log(new_s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```js
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback){
    var newArray = [];
    // Add your code below this line
        for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
           newArray.push(callback(this[i]));
        } 
    // Add your code above this line
    return newArray;
  }
  
  
console.log([1, 2, 3].myMap(function (num) { return num + 2; }));
```

The purpose of `map` is to project a function over a value. In the case of `Array`, it "maps" the function over each value inside the array.